# Aggregation problem in MongoDB plugin for Grafana

Tags: mongodb, grafana

I am using this wonderful plugin https://github.com/JamesOsgood/mongodb-grafana to connect to MongoDB from Grafana.
However I am struggling with aggregating in the MongoDB - Syntax.

My collection contains debugging infos about http-requests.
So each document looks like:

```
{
 "method" : "dosomething",
 "start" : "2021-12-18T14:58:01.496+00:00",
 "logType" : "ERROR"
...
}
```

My goal is to count all documents, that have logType "ERROR", method "dosomething" and show them aggregated to 15 minutes in Grafana.

My best guess was:

```
db.extendedLogging.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      start: { $gte: "$from", $lte: "$to" },
      method: "dosomething",
      logType: "ERROR",
    },
  },
  { $sort: { start: 1 } },
  {
    $bucketAuto: {
      groupBy: "$start",
      buckets: "$dateBucketCount",
      output: { cnt: { $sum: 1 } },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: "value",
      value: "$cnt",
      ts: "$_id.min",
      _id: 0,
    },
  },
])
```

However this doesn't aggregate to 15 minutes intervals and leads to a straight line on 1.
([time series with constant line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oqVK.png) )

If I play around with the query options in Grafana the value changes, but it remains totally constant (which it is not).

So my guess is, I am doing something wrong in the "cnt" part of the query, but I am not sure how it should work.

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: As I see the repo has not been developed about for 3 years, I don't recommend you to integrate such kinds of these modules inside your project

Comment: I know there is a risk, but it actually works well for some other use cases and the only alternative is an enterprise subscription for Grafana, which is not an option for this use case. I think I am failing to understand the MongoDB query syntax properly tbh.